# Got stuck trying to install TensorFlow on Mac M1

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

I have been trying to install TensorFlow on my Macbook Air with a M1 chip.
Using Python 3.9.7.
Originally was on MacOS 11, but subsequently upgraded to 12.01

At first, I tried these instructions [https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-on-the-m1-mac-410bb36b776] but got stuck when trying to execute

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force --no-dependencies https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_addons_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
```

ERROR: tensorflow_addons_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

So I tried to follow these instructions [https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#macos_1] to compile TensorFlow, but when I try

```
bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get these errors:
ERROR: /Users/scottbrown/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/python/BUILD:62:10: Target '//tensorflow/lite/python:tflite_convert' depends on toolchain '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin', which cannot be found: error loading package '@local_config_cc//': cannot load '@local_config_cc_toolchains//:osx_archs.bzl': no such file'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed

When I try

```
pip3 install tensorflow-macos
```

I get this error:
Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/gz/28jpdfcd3b3g4pm7zl0wmrkh0000gn/T/tmpz_m057zj
cwd: /private/var/folders/gz/28jpdfcd3b3g4pm7zl0wmrkh0000gn/T/pip-install-kz29fkw2/h5py_0747e63c821445b6944ecb4fc6b2d1e1

Answer (score 7):

I'm basing my answer on the article from Prabhat Kumar Sahu:
[How to install Tensorflow on M1 Mac the easy way](https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706)

#### Set up environment

Make sure you have homebrew, xcode, and miniforge installed.

create a virtual environment

```sh
conda create --name mlp python=3.8
```

activate environment

```
conda activate mlp
```

#### Install tensorflow for mac-os

> (sets up the wheel files etc.)

```sh
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal
```

That's it. You should have the environment all ready to go.  Look at [Prabhat's article for a sample Jupyter Notebook test](https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706) for an example of how to benchmark/test your environment.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying.  I just tried these steps.  I clicked the link to Prabhat's article and followed steps 5 and 6 there since it seems like your instructions correspond with his earlier steps.  When I tried executing the suggested code in Jupyter Notebook, I get this error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-59309fb5a3f1> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
-> 2 print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'

Comment: @ScottBrown were you able to get tensorflow running on jupyter?

Comment: Yes... now this is over a year ago, but I believe the missing step was to execute this command:
conda activate tensorflow

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys I had the same issue **but I fixed it with the following instructions** :

NOTE: If using conda environment built against pre-macOS 11 SDK use:

```
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

otherwise, you will get errors like: “not a supported wheel on this platform”

**STEPS :**

> OS Requirements macOS 12.0+ (latest beta)

Currently Not Supported
Multi-GPU support
Acceleration for Intel GPUs
V1 TensorFlow Networks

Installation Instructions

**Step 1: Environment setup**
**CPU TYPE x86: AMD**

Create virtual environment (recommended):

```
python3 -m venv ~/tensorflow-metal

source ~/tensorflow-metal/bin/activate

python -m pip install -U pip
```

NOTE: python version 3.8 required

**CPU TYPE : arm64 : Apple Silicon**

**Download and install Conda env:**

chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate

OR
conda env create --file=environment.yml --name tf_m1
and then activate tf_m1

Install the TensorFlow dependencies:

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
```

When upgrading to new base TensorFlow version, we recommend:

## uninstall existing tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal

```
python -m pip uninstall tensorflow-macos
python -m pip uninstall tensorflow-metal
```

## Upgrade tensorflow-deps

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps --force-reinstall
```

## or point to specific conda environment

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps --force-reinstall -n my_env
```

tensorflow-deps versions are following base TensorFlow versions so:

**For v2.5:**

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps==2.5.0
```

**For v2.6:**

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps==2.6.0
```

NOTE: Python versions 3.8 and 3.9 supported

**Step 2: Install base TensorFlow**

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

**NOTE: If using conda environment built against pre-macOS 11 SDK use:**

```
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

**otherwise you will get errors like: “not a supported wheel on this
platform**

**Step 3: Install tensorflow-metal plugin**

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```